# How to store dynamic HTML table to localStorage in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic, html-table, local-storage

New coder here. I have a dynamic html table with details by the user input and the time they input the details. But I need to store the data that even if I refresh or close the browser, it will retain..

Here is the html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Down Logsheet</title>

    <!-- css file link -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>   
<body>
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="add-logsheet">           
        </div>   
        <div class="logsheet-table">
            <h3 class="title">エラー履歴システム</h3>
            
            <p1 id="title">入力情報</p1>
            <div class="sub-box">
                
                <div class="operatorside"style="width:50%; float:left">
                <label id="operator">依頼者</label>

                <input type="text"
                id="lotid"
                name="lotid"
                value=""
                style="width:20%"
                placeholder="ロットNo。">

                <input type="text"
                id="employeeid"
                name="employeeid"
                value=""
                style="width:20%"
                placeholder="依頼者名を入力">

                <!--Enter Error instead of selection-->
                <!--<input type="text"
                id="errorid"
                name="errorid"
                value=""
                placeholder="入力エラー内容">-->
                <!--<div id="div1"></div>-->
                
                <select style="width:20%" name="errorid" id="errorid" type="text" onchange="showfield(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
                    <option value="noinput" disabled selected>エラーを選択</option>
                    <option value="電極スクラッチ">電極スクラッチ</option>
                    <option value="フィーダNG">フィーダNG</option>
                    <option value="電極崩壊">電極崩壊</option>
                    <option value="突出誤差">突出誤差</option>
                    <option value="障害">障害</option> 
                    <option value="Other">その他</option>
                      
                </select>

                <!--<a href=\A>--><button id="submit-button2" class="btn"onclick="firstinput()">提出する</button><!--</a>-->
                <div id="div1"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="maintenanceside" style="width:50%; float:right">
                <label id="maintenance">KP</label>
                <input type="text"
                id="maintenanceid"
                name="maintenanceid"
                value=""
                style="width:20%"  
                placeholder="KPを入力"
                disabled>
                        
                <input type="text"
                id="actiondone"
                name="actiondone"
                style="width:20%"  
                placeholder="是正措置"
                disabled>

                <select style="width:20%" disabled name="ackid" id="ackid" type="text">
                    <option value="" disabled selected>謝辞</option>
                    <option value="NOT OK">NOT OK</option>
                    <option value="OK">OK</option>
                </select>
                <!--<a href=\a>--><button disabled id="submit-button1" class="btn" onclick="addToTable()">提出する</button><!--</a><br>-->               
                
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="table-body2">
                <!--<label for="StatusTable" style="text-align: center;" style="width:100%">STATUS</label>-->
                <!--<p style="text-align: center;">STATUS</p>-->
                
                <table id="StatusTable" style="width=100%" border="2">
                    <caption class="captionstatus">情報</caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <!--<th style="width:5%">No.</th>-->
                            <th style="width:20%">ロットNo。</th> 
                            <th style="width:20%">発生日時</th>
                            <th style="width:20%">依頼者</th>
                            <th style="width:40%">エラー内容</th>  
                            <!--<th style="width:10%">KP</th>-->            
                        </tr>

                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="status">
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div class="table-body">               
                <!--<label for="myTable" style="text-align: left">機器No. SW 39</label>-->
                <table id="myTable" style="width=100%" border ="2">
                    <caption class="mainstatus">機器No.<input type="text" id="machineid" value="" style="width:5%"> </caption>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th style="width:5%">番号No.</th>
                            <th style="width:5%">機器No.</th>
                            <th style="width:5%">ロットNo。</th> 
                            <th style="width:10%">依頼者</th>
                            <th style="width:15%">エラー内容</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">KP</th>
                            <th style="width:15%">是正措置</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">操作可能</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">発生日時</th>
                            <th style="width:10%">終了日時</th> 
                            <th style="width:10%">合計時間 (分)</th> 
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody id="main">

                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <h3 class="maintablefooter" id="no-data">機器のダウンタイム監視(No Data Available)</h3>
                <div class="footer">
                    
                <button id="exportToExcel" onclick="exportTableToExcel('myTable')">エクスポートデータ(.xls)</button>
                <!--<button id="button5" class="btn"onclick="TestLang()">try</button>-->
                <p1 type="text" value="datenow" id="datenow"></p1>
                  
                <!-- <button id="submit-button3" class="btn"onclick="save_data()">SAVE</button> -->
                <!-- <button id="submit-button4" class="btn"onclick="load_data()">LOAD</button> -->
                
                </div>
            </div>      
        </div> 
    </div>
    
</body> 


<!--java script source file-->

   <!--script-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="index.js"></script>
   </html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tabletoexcel.js"></script>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="datetime.js"></script>
</html>
<script type="text/javascript" src="tableborder.js"></script>
</html>
```

The table that I want to retain is the 'myTable' with a tbody 'main'

Here is the javascript:

```
var employeeid= [];
var errorid= [];
var machineid=[];
var index= [];
var maintenanceid= [];
var ackid= [];
var c= 1;
var g= 1;
var time1= [];
var time2= [];
var actiondone= [];
var employeeid2=[];
var errorid2=[];
var index1= [];
var lotid= [];
var lotid2= [];
var time1st= [];
var totaltime =[];
var endTime=[];
var starT=[];
var time3=[];
var errorencountered=[];
var tr4=[];
var trial=[];

function firstinput(){
   
    var sub11= document.getElementById('employeeid').value;    
    let errorencountered=document.getElementById('errorid').value;
    if (errorencountered==='Other'){
      var sub22=document.getElementById('others123').value;
    }
    else {
      var sub22=document.getElementById('errorid').value;
    }
   
    var sub33= document.getElementById('lotid').value;
    const sub55= new Date();  
    starT=new Date().getTime();
    var sub69=document.getElementById('machineid').value;

    if(sub11&&sub22&&sub69 !=='')
    {

      employeeid= [...employeeid,sub11];
      errorid= [...errorid,sub22];
      time1= [...time1,sub55];
      index1= [...index1,g];  
      lotid= [...lotid,sub33];
  
    displayTable1();

    }
    else
        alert("入力不完全(Input Incomplete)");
}



document.getElementById('status').appendChild(tr4);
}

function displayTable1(){  
  const length= employeeid.length;
  tr4=document.createElement('tr');

  for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
  {
        tr4.innerHTML='';
      
        var ad33=document.createElement('td');
        ad33.innerHTML= lotid[i];
        tr4.appendChild(ad33);

        var ad5=document.createElement('td');
        ad5.innerHTML= time1[i];
        tr4.appendChild(ad5);
           
        var ad2=document.createElement('td');
        ad2.innerHTML= employeeid[i];
        tr4.appendChild(ad2);

        var ad3=document.createElement('td');
        ad3.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        ad3.style.color= "black";
        ad3.innerHTML= errorid[i];
        tr4.appendChild(ad3);

        document.getElementById('status').appendChild(tr4);  
  }
  g++;

  document.getElementById("submit-button2").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("submit-button1").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("employeeid").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("errorid").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("lotid").disabled = true;
  document.getElementById("maintenanceid").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("ackid").disabled = false;
  document.getElementById("actiondone").disabled = false;

}

function addToTable(){
   
  document.getElementById('no-data').style.display="none";
  var sub1= document.getElementById('employeeid').value;

  let errorencountered=document.getElementById('errorid').value;
  if (errorencountered==='Other'){
    var sub2=document.getElementById('others123').value;
  }
  else {
    var sub2=document.getElementById('errorid').value;
  }

  var sub3= document.getElementById('maintenanceid').value;
  var sub4= document.getElementById('ackid').value;
  var sub7= document.getElementById('actiondone').value;
  var sub33 =document.getElementById('lotid').value;
  var sub69 =document.getElementById('machineid').value;

  const sub6= new Date().getTime();
  const sub68= new Date();
  var sub77 = ((sub6-starT)/1000)/60;
  sub77 = sub77.toFixed(2);  
 
  if(sub1&&sub2&&sub3&&sub4 !=='')

  {
  machineid= [...machineid,sub69];
  employeeid2= [...employeeid2,sub1];
  errorid2= [...errorid2,sub2];
  maintenanceid= [...maintenanceid,sub3];
  actiondone= [...actiondone,sub7];
  lotid2= [...lotid2,sub33];
  ackid= [...ackid,sub4];
  time3= [...time3,sub68];
  index= [...index,c];
  totaltime=[...totaltime,sub77]; 
  
  myDeleteFunction();
  displayTable();
  
  }

  else 
      alert("入力不完全(Input Incomplete)");
  
}

function displayTable(){

    const length= employeeid2.length;
    var tr=document.createElement('tr');

    for(var i=0;i<length;i++)
    {
        tr.innerHTML='';
        var td1=document.createElement('td');
        td1.innerHTML= index[i];
        tr.appendChild(td1);

        var td89=document.createElement('td');
        td89.innerHTML= machineid[i];
        tr.appendChild(td89);

        var td33=document.createElement('td');
        td33.innerHTML= lotid2[i];
        tr.appendChild(td33);

        var td2=document.createElement('td');
        td2.innerHTML= employeeid2[i];
        tr.appendChild(td2);

        var td3=document.createElement('td');
        td3.innerHTML= errorid2[i];
        tr.appendChild(td3);
       
        var td4=document.createElement('td');
        td4.innerHTML= maintenanceid[i];
        tr.appendChild(td4);

        var td5=document.createElement('td');
        td5.innerHTML= actiondone[i];
        tr.appendChild(td5);

        var td6=document.createElement('td');
        td6.innerHTML= ackid[i];
        tr.appendChild(td6);

        var td7=document.createElement('td');
        td7.innerHTML= time1[i];
        tr.appendChild(td7);

        var td8=document.createElement('td');
        td8.innerHTML= time3[i];
        tr.appendChild(td8);

        var td9=document.createElement('td');
        td9.innerHTML=totaltime[i];
        tr.appendChild(td9);

        document.getElementById('main').appendChild(tr);
    }
    c++;

    document.getElementById('employeeid').value='';
    document.getElementById('errorid').value='';
    document.getElementById('maintenanceid').value='';
    document.getElementById('ackid').value='';
    document.getElementById('actiondone').value='';
    document.getElementById('lotid').value='';
    document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';

    document.getElementById("submit-button2").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("submit-button1").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("employeeid").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("errorid").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("lotid").disabled = false;
    document.getElementById("maintenanceid").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("ackid").disabled = true;
    document.getElementById("actiondone").disabled = true;
}

function myDeleteFunction() {
  document.getElementById("StatusTable").deleteRow(1);
}

function showfield(name){
  if(name=='Other')document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='その他: <input type="text" name="other" value="" id="others123" placeholder="ご指定ください" >';
  else document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML='';
}
```

I expect that the 'myTable' with a tbody of 'main' will retain.. I am new to javascript and not yet familiar with localStorage, and I can't seem to find a guide on localStorage regarding with the sequence that I've made in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having a bunch of arrays, use 1 array with a bunch of objects. Each object tracks all the data for a single employee. eg:

```
var empToSave = {
    employeeid2: employeeid2,
    errorid2: errorid2,
    machineid: machineid,
    maintenanceid: maintenanceid,
    ackid: ackid,
    lotid2: lotid2,
    time3: time3,
    index: index,
    totaltime: totaltime,
};
```

You can push the object into the array like so

```
var dataToSave = [];
dataToSave.push(empToSave);
```

Then you can store strings of data in localstorage... convert your array of rows into a string with JSON.stringify(), then store it like so...

```
// Convert the data to JSON string and save to localStorage
localStorage.setItem('myTableData', JSON.stringify(dataToSave));
```

Then you can load the data out of the localStorage again, then parse it back into the array of objects like so...

```
var storedData = localStorage.getItem('myTableData');
var parsedData = JSON.parse(storedData);
```

Comment: Thank you, Ryano. I am currently studying your solution, I will get back to you.